# Eurodollars: How many days in 3 month LIBOR?

Tags: interest-rate

The [CME webpage](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_contractSpecs_futures.html) states that Eurodollar futures settle to 3 month LIBOR:

[image: ED settlement]

My question is regarding the underlying LIBOR term deposit rate mentioned in the contract spec.  Suppose today is Tuesday, Feb 26, 2019 and 3 month LIBOR is 2.57%.

1. Is it true that the 2.57% rate refers to a borrowing period starting Thursday, Feb 28, 2019 (settlement date T+2) through Tuesday, 5/28/2019, a period of **89 days**?

Suppose now it is one day later: Wednesday, Feb 27, 2019, and 3 month LIBOR is unchanged at 2.57%.

2. Is it true that the 2.57% rate refers to a borrowing period starting Friday, Mar 1, 2019 (settlement date T+2) through Wed, 6/1/2019, a period of **92 days**?

Suppose finally that all economic considerations for interest rates remain unchanged between Feb 26 and Feb 27 (i.e. no changes in credit quality, supply/demand, etc.).

3. Would you expect the 3 month rate to change (increase) due to the **extra 3 days** in the borrowing period?  I.e. might 3 month LIBOR differ between Feb 26 and Feb 27 due only to the longer lending period?  Or, do lenders not make this distinction when defining a "3 month" borrow rate?

Comment: Based on interpolating between the 2M and 3M USD LIBORs, a difference of 3 days in maturity should mean a rate difference of about 0.004%, which is somewhat less than typical day-to-day rate fluctuations.